# Import Yahoo Contacts in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code for importing Yahoo contacts from an address book, but it imports only the top 30 contacts, not all of the contacts.

Anyways, I think another alternative (and better) way of doing it is by using another latest Yahoo API.

```
        private const string _addressBookUrl = "http://address.mail.yahoo.com/allcontacts";
        //private const string _addressBookUrl = "http://address.yahoo.com/yab/us/Yahoo_ab.csv?loc=us&.rand=1671497644&A=H&Yahoo_ab.csv";  
        private const string _authUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?";
        private const string _loginPage = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login";
        private const string _userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3";

    [TestMethod()]
    public void Yahoo()
    {
       List<ContactDetails> lst = new List<ContactDetails>();
       lst = GetYahooContacts("UserId", "Password");
       Assert.IsNotNull(lst);
    }


    public List<ContactDetails> GetYahooContacts(string _username, string _pass)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = _userAgent;
            webclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            byte[] firstResponse = webclient.DownloadData(_loginPage);                
            string firstRes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(firstResponse);

            NameValueCollection postToLogin = new NameValueCollection();
            Regex regex = new Regex("type=\"hidden\" name=\"(.*?)\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match match = regex.Match(firstRes);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                if (match.Groups[0].Value.Length > 0)
                {
                    postToLogin.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
                }
                match = regex.Match(firstRes, match.Index + match.Length);
            }

            postToLogin.Add(".save", "Sign In");
            postToLogin.Add(".persistent", "y");

            string login = _username;
            postToLogin.Add("login", login);
            postToLogin.Add("passwd", _pass);

            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = _userAgent;
            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = _loginPage;
            webclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = webclient.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

            webclient.UploadValues(_authUrl, postToLogin);

            string cookie = webclient.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];


            string newCookie = string.Empty;
            string[] tmp1 = cookie.Split(',');
            foreach (string var in tmp1)
            {
                string[] tmp2 = var.Split(';');
                newCookie = String.IsNullOrEmpty(newCookie) ? tmp2[0] : newCookie + ";" + tmp2[0];
            }

            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = newCookie;
            byte[] thirdResponse = webclient.DownloadData(_addressBookUrl);                
            string thirdRes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(thirdResponse);
            List<ContactDetails> lst = new List<ContactDetails>();
            lst = ParseYahooResponse(thirdRes);
            return lst;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }


    private List<ContactDetails> ParseYahooResponse(string _response)
    {
        List<ContactDetails> ContactList = new List<ContactDetails>();
        _response = _response.Substring(_response.IndexOf("InitialContacts"), (_response.IndexOf("InitialBucket") - _response.IndexOf("InitialContacts")));

        List<YahooContacts> Contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YahooContacts>>(_response.Substring(_response.IndexOf('['), (_response.LastIndexOf(']') - _response.IndexOf('[')) + 1));

        foreach (YahooContacts oYahooContacts in Contacts)
        {
            ContactDetails ocontacts = new ContactDetails();
            ocontacts.Name = Convert.ToString(oYahooContacts.ContactName);
            ocontacts.EmailAddress = Convert.ToString(oYahooContacts.Email);
            ContactList.Add(ocontacts);

        }
        return ContactList;
    }
}

public class YahooContacts
    {
        private string contactId;
        private string contactName;
        private string email;


    public string ContactID
    {
        get { return contactId; }
        set { contactId = value; }
    }

    public string ContactName
    {
        get { return contactName; }
        set { contactName = value; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

These are bad variable names, they should be descriptive of what kind of values they contain:

```
string[] tmp1 = cookie.Split(',');
string[] tmp2 = var.Split(';');
```

Moreover, `tmp1` isn't even necessary since you only use it once.

Also avoid things like `oYahooContacts`, just name them `yahooContacts`.

Don't abbreviate, e.g. `_pass`. It isn't necessary and only makes code harder to read.

---

I don't think `ParseYahooResponse` is descriptive enough. Sure, that method does parse the response, but more importantly it returns a list of contacts.

---

Variables should be camelCase:

```
List<ContactDetails> ContactList = new List<ContactDetails>();
List<YahooContacts> Contacts
```

---

I don't think `YahooContacts` is a good class name, for one it is a plural. It can also be simplified by using Auto-Implemented Properties, e.g.

```
public string ContactID {get;set;}
```

---

Things like `private const string _addressBookUrl` belong in a separate class IMHO, or perhaps in a config file.

Why do you name your parameter `_username` and then assign it to the variable `login`? Plus in your test method you call it `"UserId"`.

---

I'm not a fan of this:

```
postToLogin.Add(".save", "Sign In");
postToLogin.Add(".persistent", "y");
postToLogin.Add("login", login);
postToLogin.Add("passwd", _pass);
```

This reeks of magic strings. I would be tempted to make this a class of its own, which then can be converted to a `NameValueCollection`, and things like `".save"` would be constants in that class, perhaps.

At least I'd move the whole `postToLogin` logic to its own class, have it parse the response and return a `NameValueCollection`.

Actually, that goes for most of the code. I'd move some code from `GetYahooContacts` at least to separate methods, certainly the lines where you create a new cookie. The whole method is rather hard to figure out, for instance I didn't quite understand why you assigned to `webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie]` multiple times until I noticed `webclient.UploadValues(_authUrl, postToLogin);` happens between those two assignments.

I'd much prefer it if the logic in that method was distributed over several shorter method, so the logic becomes clearer, e.g. do a download, parse the response/create the `postToLogin` NameValueCollection, do an upload, create the cookie, do a download, get the contact details.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a whole lot of time right now, but I noticed this while scanning through your code.

> ```
>       catch (Exception e)
>       {
>           throw e;
>       }
> ```

There's no point in catching an exception just to re throw it. This adds unnecessary overhead to the code. You might as well just remove the `try...catch` block.